# Ember: camelCase helper references not recognised

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I upgraded Ember CLI from 2.4.6 to 2.8.0. After this, the helpers referred by camelCase names in the template are throwing the error `Assertion Failed: A helper named "helperName" could not be found`. If I change the references to `helper-name` from `helperName`, things work fine.

Comment: upvote if you find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent ember versions, if your helper has a dash in it `(helpers/helper-name.js)`, then call it using curly braces in your template as `{{helper-name}}`. In your case, your helper is `dasherized` but you are invoking it with `camelCase`.

In ember `2.4`: [Reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_helper-names)

`Unlike components, helpers do not require a dash (-) character in their name.`

In ember `2.8`: [Reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_helper-names)

`Unlike components, which require a dash in the name to follow the Custom Element spec, helper names can be single or multi-word. If your helper's name is multi-word, it should be dasherized in your template.`